# imshow colored image, wrongly displayed as blue

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, opencv

I am trying to read and display a tiff image with opencv.
I tried different reading modes in imread (-1,0,1,2)
The result of the code below displays the image wrongly as blue only while it is colored.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def readImagesAndTimes():
  # List of exposure times
  times = np.array([ 1/30.0, 0.25, 2.5, 15.0 ], dtype=np.float32)

  # List of image filenames
  filenames = ["img01.tif", "img02.tif", "img03.tif", "img04.tif", "img05.tif"]
  images = []
  for filename in filenames:
    im = cv2.imread("./data/hdr_images/" + filename, -1)
    images.append(im)

  return images, times

images, times = readImagesAndTimes()
for im in images:
    print(im.shape)
    plt.imshow(im, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)
```

Original image:

[[image: original]]

Displayed blue image of the code :

[[image: blue]]

Comment: will try it within the day and let you know if it is working, nonetheless thanks a lot

Comment: rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(rgb, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)

This worked while    cv2.imshow('image',im)
opens a new window running from jupyter in pycharm. 
Stil thanks a lot for your help and the working solution.
PS what cv2 version are u using?

Comment: you're welcome. I am using opencv 3.3.1-dev

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that opencv uses `bgr` color mode and matplotlib uses `rgb` color mode. Therefore the red and blue color channels are switched.

You can easily fix that problem by proving matplotlib an rgb image or by using `cv2.imshow` function.

1. BGR to RGB conversion:

   ```
   for im in images:
       # convert bgr to rgb 
       rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
       plt.imshow(rgb, cmap = plt.cm.Spectral)
   ```
2. opencv's imshow function:

   ```
   for im in images:
       # no color conversion needed, because bgr is also used by imshow
       cv2.imshow('image',im)
   ```